# Static table not showing

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I created a table view controller and from drop down in Xcode selected content to be static cells. I placed buttons in those cells but when I run I get an empty table. I didn't enter any code in the TableViewController class as I thought this was not needed.

How can this be fixed?

This is the way it looks in Xcode and then when it runs in simulator:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check your autolayout constraints.

Comment: @Woodstock it wasn't the constraints but it was the tableview methods as mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may miss some stuff:

**1)** Check whether your tableView has set the class named as that on in your code. You find the input field to type the name of the class in Attributes inspector of the tableView.

**2)** Check whether you implemented methods, that comform to UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource Protocol.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // I see you only have 1 section now
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
//you should return appropriate number
   return 3
}
```

**3)** Check whether your table is properly connected from Storyboard to your UIViewController =>

if your tableView is inside UIViewController, check whether you set delegate and datasource for tableView in your controller (CTRL drag from table to FileOwner - rounded yellow icon in storyboard scene frame.)

Comment: Thanks totally didn't know that was necessary when setting up a static table

Answer (score 2):

using static cells, it's not necessary to implement numberOfSections and numberOfRowsInSection. By default, at runtime you get the static cell(s) as implemented in the designer.
However, if you do implement these methods and, by error, return 0: No cell is shown at runtime.

Comment: I still had the default TableViewController class which was returning 0 for number of rows. That would explain it!

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the answer above:

1) Make sure the tableview is hooked up as both the datasource and delegate.

2) Make sure these two lines of code are modified to your table. Default is to return 0 (an empty table) so you need to modify them accordingly. You can also choose to comment them out completely (what I did).

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // I see you only have 1 section now
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
//you should return appropriate number
   return 3
}
```